# Transferring bitcoins from my blockchain addresses to an exchange?

Tags: transactions

What are the specific steps, in order, required to transfer my bitcoins from their blockchain wallets to a bitcoin exchange?  Please be specific.  Thanks

Comment: 1) Are you asking about a blockchain as it relates to bitcoin, or the service named blockchain.info? 2) Are you asking for a technical description, or instructions? 3) Have you tried to research your question elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "blockchain.info".

- Go to your exchange, deposit/bitcoins section. It should give you a bitcoin address, copy it.
- go to your wallet, "send money"
- enter the copied address and the desired amount
- hit "send"

Answer (score 0):

1. Your wallet contains one or more bitcoin addresses that are *yours*. Pick one and copy it to your clipboard.
2. Go to the deposit section of your exchange, select "Deposit bitcoins".
3. Paste in your bitcoin address, plus type in the number of bitcoins to transfer in.

That's it.

Comment: This post is a mess, who upvoted and why?